# how to implement "structs with methods" in idiomatic typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm coming from a golang background and I'm unclear how to idiomatically do the following:

```
export interface BatchUser {
  id: Id
  displayName: string
  age: number  
}

interface Hashable {
  toString(): string;
}

export class HashableBatchUser implements Hashable, BatchUser {
  id: Id = ""
  displayName: string = ""
  age: number = 0

  constructor(user: BatchUser) {
    this.id = user.id
    this.displayName = user.displayName
    this.age = user.age
  }

  toString(): string {
    return this.id
  }
}
```

I'd like to interact with the class as if it were a plain object (user.id, user.age etc...) with easy construction.
How can the above be DRY'ed out? I'm repeating the properties too much.

Comment: Except for using `Obejct.assign(this, user)` in the constructor and perhaps not specifying the type of fields in the class if they are initialized with values (both of which are debatable) your code is as DRY as it can be

Comment: If you don't require the copy constructor, you could instead do `constructor(public id: Id = "", public displayName = "", public age = 0) {}` and go from eight lines to one.